# django не удаётся сохранить json в jsonfield

Tags: django, json, django-rest-framework

Есть условная модель:

```
class JsonModel(models.Model):
    jsonfield = models.JSONField(blank = True)
```

при попытке отправки апи запроса:
"jsonfield": {
"additionalProp10": "string",
"additionalProp2": "string",
"additionalProp3": "string"
},
получаю ошибку:
ОШИБКА:  ошибочный литерал массива: "{"additionalProp10": "string", "additionalProp2": "string", "additionalProp3": "string"}"
LINE 1: ... '2023-12-14T20:30:09.337000+03:00'::timestamptz, '{"additio...
В чем моя ошибка ума не приложу, толкните в сторону решения пожалуйста. Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, вам нужно отправлять в виде строки значение json-поля (ведь в сериализатор должна попадать строка, которая будет преобразована сериализаторов в json):

```
"jsonfield": '{ "additionalProp10": "string", "additionalProp2": "string", "additionalProp3": "string" }'
```

Здесь есть пример сериализации json-поля: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jsonfield-in-serializers-django-rest-framework/